# How can I solve stackoverflow exception using spring-boot and hibernate?

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-boot

I tried to make a restful API server(having login and management).
So, I made `User` and `Role` class(actually, it has more classes with the same problem).
The problem occurs here.
It makes infinite call problem.

I already tried to use `@JsonManagedReference` and remove `fetch=FetchType.EAGER`.
The first, it print error `Content type 'application/json;charset=UTF-8' not supported`. I guessed it didn't work in my restful API.
Another is the same error, infinite root.

This is my `User` class.

```
public class User implements UserDetails {
    @Id
    private String username;
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String password;
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String passwordQuestion;
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String passwordAnswer;
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String email;

    @ManyToMany//(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JsonManagedReference
    private Set<Role> roles = new HashSet<Role>();

    ...
}
```

And this is my Role class.

```
public class Role implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long id;
    @Column(nullable=false)
    private String rolename;
    @ManyToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    private Set<User> users = new HashSet<User>();

    public void addUser(User user) {
        users.add(user);
    }
}
```

How can I solve this problem?

---

Additional
This is whole error message in console.
I added `@JsonBackReference` at `users` and `roles` and removed `@JsonManagedReference`.

```
2019-06-21 17:29:09.667  WARN 16596 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] .c.j.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter : Failed to evaluate Jackson deserialization for type [[simple type, class com.t3q.userManage.model.User]]: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Multiple back-reference properties with name 'defaultReference'
```

This is part of my controller.

```
public class UserController {

//  private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(UserController.class);

    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    @Autowired
    private SiteRepository siteRepository;

    @Autowired
    private RoleRepository roleRepository;

    @Autowired
    AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

    @Autowired
    JwtTokenProvider jwtTokenProvider;

    @Autowired
    PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;

//  private CryptoUtil passwordEncoder = new CryptoUtil();

    @PostMapping("/signup/{siteURL}")
    public User signUp(@PathVariable String siteURL, @Valid @RequestBody User user) throws Exception {
        User userSaved = getUser(user.getUsername());
//      Site site = siteRepository.save(new Site(0, siteURL));
        Site site = siteRepository.findBySiteURL(siteURL);
        Role userRole = roleRepository.findByRolename("ROLE_USER");
        Role adminRole = roleRepository.findByRolename("ROLE_ADMIN");
        if (userSaved == null) {
            userSaved = userRepository.save(User.builder().username(user.getUsername())
                                                        .password(passwordEncoder.encode(user.getPassword()))
                                                        .passwordQuestion(user.getPasswordQuestion())
                                                        .passwordAnswer(user.getPasswordAnswer())
                                                        .email(user.getEmail())
                                                        .roles(new HashSet<Role>() {
                                                            {
                                                                add(userRole);
                                                                add(adminRole);
                                                            }
                                                        })
                                                        .sites(new HashSet<Site>() {
                                                            {
                                                                add(site);
                                                            }
                                                        })
                                                        .build());
            addUserToSite(userSaved, site);
            addUserToRole(userSaved, userRole);
            addUserToRole(userSaved, adminRole);
        } else {
            throw new Exception("User " + userSaved.getUsername() + " already exists.");
        }
        return userSaved;
    }
...
}
```

Should I recover `@JsonManagedReference`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem using `@JsonIgnore`. And I added fetch type because it also occurs error.

```
@JsonIgnore
@ManyToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
private Set<User> users = new HashSet<User>();
```

It works in my restful API.

Answer (score 1):

My best advice to you is to never return any object annotated with `@Entity` as a return type of your controller (even wrapped around ResponseEntity). Create data transfer objects (DTOs). In your case, it is especially important because you do not want to reveal the password field (event if its hashed). DTOs will slightly increase boilerplate code (lombok can help), however, it will significantly organize your code and make it way more comfortable to work with.

Create a method that will transfer your entity into a DTO (for retrievals) and create a method that will translate your DTO into an entity (for inserts and updates).

> This is how your entity will look like:

```
@Data
@Builder
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class User implements UserDetails {

    @Id
    private String username;
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String password;
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String passwordQuestion;
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String passwordAnswer;
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String email;

    @ManyToMany//(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private Set<Role> roles = new HashSet<Role>();
}
```

> Then, create your DTO:

```
@Data
@Builder
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
class UserDto {
    private String username;
    private String password;
    private String passwordQuestion;
    private String passwordAnswer;
    private String email;
    private Set<String> roles = new HashSet<String>();
}
```

> Finally, create mapping methods in your UserService:

```
@Service
@RequiredArgsConstructor
class UserService {

    private final PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;

    // Update which attributes you will reveal in the dto when retrieving it
    public UserDto toDto(User user) {
        return UserDto.builder()
                .username(user.getUsername())
                .passwordQuestion(user.getPasswordQuestion())
                .email(user.getEmail())
                .build();
    }

    public User toEntity(UserDto userDto) {
        return User.builder()
                .username(userDto.getUsername())
                .password(passwordEncoder.encode(userDto.getPassword()))
                .email(userDto.getEmail())
                .passwordQuestion(userDto.getPasswordQuestion())
                .passwordAnswer(userDto.getPasswordAnswer())
                .build();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to add JsonBackReference to the users Set in the Role class as well:

```
@JsonBackReference
@ManyToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
private Set<User> users = new HashSet<User>();
```

Comment: I tried it and the exception occurs,`Content type 'application/json;charset=UTF-8' not supported` . And I used lombok to create getter/setter and constructors(no args, all args).

Comment: Can you please show the code of the RestController and the whole StackTrace.

Comment: I modified my question. Do you have other answers to my problem except for my answer in bellow?

Comment: why did you remove JsonManagedReference? One side has to be JsonManagedReference and the other JsonBackReference?

Comment: I didn't know for JsonManagedReference and JsonBackReference. Now, I learn it. However, there is a problem.... When I used it, it occurs error, `Cannot handle managed/back reference 'defaultReference': back reference type (java.util.Set) not compatible with managed type`.